# Abstract vector form for integral of wavefunctions in subspace

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Landau, Lifshitz "Quantum mechanics (non-relativistic theory)" density matrix is given in the form
$$\rho(x,x^\prime)=\int\Psi(q,x)\Psi^\ast(q,x^\prime)\text{d}q,$$
where $x$ is set of coordinates for the inner system and $q$ is set of coordinates for outer system.

I'm trying to rewrite it in abstract (representationless) form for density operator, i.e. using the fact that $\Psi(q,x)=\left<q,x\middle|\Psi\right>$ and $\Psi^\ast(q,x^\prime)=\left<\Psi\middle|q,x^\prime\right>$.

It seems to hold that $\left|q,x\right>=\left|q\right>\otimes\left|x\right>$. At the same time, as LL say, $\Psi$ doesn't generally fall into a product of functions of $x$ and $q$ alone, which I interpret that $\left|\Psi\right>$ can't be written as a tensor product of some two vectors in subspace spanned by $\left|q\right>$ and by $\left|x\right>$.

So, what I try:
$$\rho(x,x^\prime)=\int\Psi(q,x)\Psi^\ast(q,x^\prime)\text{d}q=\int\left<q,x\vphantom{^\prime}\middle|\Psi\right>\left<\Psi\middle|q,x^\prime\right>\text{d}q=\int\left.\left(\left<q\vphantom{^\prime}\right|\otimes\left<x\vphantom{^\prime}\right|\right)\middle|\Psi\right>\left<\Psi\middle|\left(\left|q\right>\otimes\left|x^\prime\right>\right)\right.\text{d}q$$

Clearly, the result here must be a scalar depending on $x$ and $x^\prime$, as expected, but it is only a representation of the density operator. So I want to somehow get rid of $\left|x^\prime\right>$ and $\left<x\right|$, but don't have any ideas on how to expand the tensor products in parentheses.

So, my question: how can the expression I got be simplified further and rewritten in abstract representation-free form?

**Edit:**

I've realized that I can get an expression for *operator* if I multiply everything by $\left|x\vphantom{^\prime}\right>$ at left side and $\left<x^\prime\right|$ at right side and then integrate over $x$ and $x^\prime$:
$$\hat \rho=\int\left|x\vphantom{^\prime}\right>\left.\left(\left<q\vphantom{^\prime}\right|\otimes\left<x\vphantom{^\prime}\right|\right)\middle|\Psi\right>\left<\Psi\middle|\left(\left|q\vphantom{^\prime}\right>\otimes\left|x^\prime\right>\right)\right.\left<x^\prime\right|\text{d}q\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}x^\prime$$

Still this is not satisfactory because I have to introduce dummy basis $\left.\middle| x\right>$.

So, the question which remains: how can I eliminate the need in dummy  $\left.\middle| x\right>$ basis? Basically it seems I need some way to define operator (whose matrix is non-rectangular in finite-dimensional case): $$\hat q=\int\left(\left|q\right>\otimes\left|x\right>\right)\left<x\right|\text{d}x,$$
but without introducing $\left.\middle|x\right>$ basis.

---

Answer (score 1):

The $q$ are not the coordinates of the full system. The $x$ are the coordinates of a sub-system and the  $q$  are the remaining coordinates, such as $x,q$ are the coordinates of the full closed system.

The main idea is in fact, that the general representation in quantum mechanics is the density matrix, and that each density matrix can be obtained from a partial trace from a pure density matrix (this is called [purification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purification_of_quantum_state) )

So we belong with a pure state $\psi$, relatively to the full system :  $ \langle q,x|\psi \rangle  = \psi(q,x)$. The pure density matrix, relatively to the full sytem, is :

$\rho_{pure} (q', x', q, x) = \psi^*(q',x') \psi(q,x)$

Now, practically, we don't have access to the $q$ degrees of freedom, and the quantities in which we are interested are represented by operators $\hat f$ acting only on the sub-system, that is acting on the $x$ degrees of freedom.

So, we have to make a partial trace on the $q$ degrees of freedom, to get a reduced density matrix $\rho_{reduced}(x',x)$, which applies only on the $x$ degrees of freedom, and which is generally a mixed density matrix, and no more a pure density matrix.

$\rho_{reduced}(x',x) = \int dq ~ \rho_{pure} (q, x', q, x) = \int dq ~\psi^*(q,x') \psi(q,x)$

The mean value of a quantity $f$ represented  by a operator $\hat f$, acting only on the sub-system, may be now written :

$\langle \hat f \rangle = \int dx [\hat f \rho_{reduced}(x',x)]_{x=x'} $

So, because generally $\rho_{reduced}$ is a mixed reduced density matrix, defined above, it is not generally possible to  rewrite it in abstract representation-free form with direct relation to the original pure state $|\psi\rangle$